# Ajax request to controller error

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am using ajax to perform a user register function. I use ajax to send the user information over to the controller which then passes the information to a model to insert the information into a database.

The insertion is done successfully as I saw the entry in my database. However for my ajax request it always returns an error.

Something I noted was that once I leave one of the fields empty, it returns a success.

my ajax script as below

```
var post_data = 
    {
        'username':user_name,
        'password':user_password,
        'email':user_email,
        'role':user_role
    };


    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url:"login_register/register_data",
        data: post_data,
        success: function(data) {
                alert('Insertion of user ok');
        },
        error: function(data)
        {
            alert('Insertion of user error ' + data.responseText);
        }
    });
```

my controller code

```
public function register_data()
{
    $this->load->database();
    $this->load->model('login_model');

    $user_name=$this->input->post('username');
    $user_password=$this->input->post('password');
    $user_email=$this->input->post('email');
    $user_role=$this->input->post('role');

    $result = $this->login_model->register_data_model($user_name,$user_password,$user_email,$user_role);

    //if($result)
        echo "true";
    //else echo "false";
}
```

my model code

```
public function register_data_model($user_name,$user_password,$user_email,$user_role)
{
    $result = $this->db->query("INSERT INTO user_table (user_name,user_password,user_email,user_role) VALUES (".$this->db->escape($user_name).",".$this->db->escape($user_password).",".$this->db->escape($user_email).",".$this->db->escape($user_role).")");
}
```

even if I dont return anything from the model and the controller, it still behaves like this. Anyone has any idea what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the post_data is correct... Try this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    url:"login_register/register_data",
    data: {user_name:'username', user_password:'password',user_email:'email',user_role:'role'},
    success: function(data) {
            alert('Insertion of user ok');
    },
    error: function(data)
    {
        alert('Insertion of user error ' + data.responseText);
    }
});
```

This would require you to get by the new key in the controller, i.e.

```
$user_name=$this->input->post('user_name');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var post_data = 
{
     username:user_name,
     password:user_password,
     email:user_email,
     role :user_role
};
```

Answer (score 0):

id suggest returning actual json formatted data instead of just true.

something along the lines of:

```
[{"successfull":"yes" }]
```

and set your php headers to application type json.

then in your javascript you can test in the success function

```
if(data[0]["successfull"].indexOf("yes") != -1)
    {
    dosomething()
    }
```

Comment: hmm its not going to the success function though, it keeps going to the error function.

Comment: Are you sure youre returning json headers?

Comment: how do we check whether i am returning json headers?

Answer (score 0):

Check the network headers to make sure you're site isn't throwing a 500 or something.